# Gradle Script to generate/clean Multiple Product Flavors

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I know how to create product flavors with gradle.I did successfully created the product flavors and apks as per product flavors.

In my project I have **8 different product flavors.**

I want a **gradle script by running this script I can generate/clean multiple apks** for all the product flavors.

Can anyone please help me?

Additional Information :: I am using android studio 0.8.3

Comment: Running `gradlew build` should generate all variants. Is this not what you experience?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`gradlew build` will generate an APK for each variant (flavor + build type).

You can also run `gradlew tasks` to list all of the tasks available, if you want to generate a few specific variants.